# Getting sorted results based on count from database where 2 tables are involved with Link to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, lambda

I have the following Stored proc that I created which works fine outside my project. However I am running in to issues with actually calling it from my project. And getting the following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult`1[Foo.getOrderedGameListByAddonCountResult]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FOO.game]'.

This is a basic snippet of the Function that is calling it when the error occurs:

```
Private Shared Function getListofGames(ByVal sortVal As SortType, ByVal listtype As listType, ByVal filterValue As String) As iList(Of game)
    Using db As New FooDataClassesDataContext
        Dim retVal As List(Of game) = Nothing
               Select Case sortVal
                    Case SortType.Name
                        retVal = db.games.OrderBy(Function(f) f.game_name).ToList
                    Case SortType.AddOnCount
                        retVal = db.getOrderedGameListByAddonCount
                End Select
       Return retVal
    End Using
End Function
```

And this is what the Sproc looks like:

```
CREATE PROC getOrderedGameListByAddonCount
as
select * from games as b
left join (
select game_addons.game_id, COUNT(*) as addonCount from game_addons
group by game_addons.game_id) as p on B.game_id = p.game_id
order by p.addonCount DESC
go
```

Without finding a meaningful way to get around the Cast issue for lists of data I have decided to use Linq to SQL statements however I am not getting anywhere with creating a Ling statement that works the same as the Sproc.

What needs to happen is there can be many addons in game_addons which contain game_id. This column is the FK and ties into the games table game_id. I am trying to return a list of games sorted by the one with the most game_addons.

I have been to MSDN, Google, and countless SO links and everything falls either really short or the Linq command i find is twisted enough I can't read it clear enough to see a framework to create one from.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being caused because I was declaring the type as a Linq to SQL database table. And the results being returned by the SPROC can't use the linq to sql table. There are 4 columns in the table that it was being declared as and the SPROC returns 6 columns. Simple fix was to just remove the type declaration in the GetListOfGames function.

This does leave me with another question now. How do I define these bastardized objects so that I can actually declare a type.